# C2365 and C2063 Class error

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to code a basic elevator simulation for a college course using classes. Right now the void CurrentFloor() function is causing a C2365 and C2063 error and i have no idea why, the other functions seem to check out but i can't figure out why this paticular function is causing those errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class elevator
{
  private:
    int StartFloor;
    int NewFloor;
    int currentFloor;
    int requestedFloor;
    char response;

public:
    elevator(int floor = 0);
    void CallElevator();
    void CurrentFloor();
    void RequestedFloor();
};
elevator::elevator(int f)
{
    StartFloor = f;
    f=1;
    cout<<"The elevator is currently on the "<<StartFloor<<" floor";
}
void elevator::CallElevator()
{
    cout<<"Would you like to call the elevator to your floor?: ";
    cin>>response;
}
void elevator::RequestedFloor()
{
    cout<<"What floor would you like to go to?: ";
    cin>>requestedFloor;
}
void elevator::CurrentFloor()
{
    cout<<"What is your current floor?";
}
int main()
{
    elevator elevatorone(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not all of us are born with Microsoft error codes wired into their brains. Could you please say what the actual errors are, and indicate their location in the code?

Comment: Do they teach debugging skills in college these days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code compiles fine and should compile fine.

Without any else to go on, I'd suggest you might have forgotten to type `()` at either the `declaration`:

```
void CurrentFloor/*()*/;
```

or `definition`:

```
void elevator::CurrentFloor/*()*/
```

That is, in your ***actual*** code. Are you compiling the source file you are editing?

Comment: I was able to get it to compile. I think it was confusing the int CurrentFloor in private with the void CurrentFloor function so i just completely changed the name of the int variable and it complied but thanks for the reply

Comment: @user1704863 Ah, that is a variation that I didn't take into account: look at `int currentFloor;` -> no `()` -> I had the right hunch :) *But* I dismissed this option since you simply provided your code, and there was no such typo there. Question For The Future: Why do you not Copy/Paste code? This is essential especially on SO: you can't afford to make typo's in code, since compilers are typically unforgiving.

Answer (score 0):

A 2 second Google for `c2365` returned as *the first hit* this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86y793k4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Rename your functions or member names...

Comment: yes i had googled the error before posting this(I'm not a complete idiot) for some reason the similarity in the name of the int currentFloor and void CurrentFloor caused the error but once i completely renamed the int variable it worked.